# Errors when implementing custom WURFL with Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, mobile, wurfl

We've a `ZEND 1.10v` website. Now we are creating a mobile site using **WURFL** browser detection. We know it's not supported for `ZEND 1.10v` therefore, we included that as Php class. Every setup seems to OK but when we visit URL following display on the site

**"There is no device with ID [generic] in the loaded WURFL Data"**

When I debug the issue it actually coming from

```
/library/WURFL/CustomDeviceRepository.php -> function init() ->
```

inside the function follwoing function called

```
$this->getDevice(WURFL_Constants::GENERIC);
```

At this time when we checked the `WURFL_Constants::GENERIC` it passes as 'generic' value. And we debugged further with `getDevice()` function it check as

```
$device = $this->persistenceStorage->load($deviceId) 
FYI : $deviceId means WURFL_Constants::GENERIC which is 'generic' value assigned.
```

Above function returns an empty value therefore, it throws the following exception

**"There is no device with ID [generic] in the loaded WURFL Data"**

We are not sure to debug further to solve this issue. Does anyone have an idea how to solve this ? We think we should define default device entry etc.

**FYI** : We've set the cache and persistence derectory permission to 777

Comment: Do you have a new updated version of WURFL? I think it came out last month.  If no, you need to update WURFL file but you have to update API providen by WURFL...

Comment: Yes, I've build with latest version. Could you please clarify more about updatging API. I mean is there a specific file ?

Comment: Yes it is :) but I don't know which file is that so I updated all API files(folder). http://sourceforge.net/projects/wurfl/files 
(btw. I use "WURFL Database")... the error is because you use new WURFL file/data with old API.

Comment: You could try http://sourceforge.net/projects/fiftyone/ for a simpler to implement solution. A blog post on zend implementation is available at http://bit.ly/V1AZR1

Comment: James how many 51Degrees have different User Agents ??

Comment: The problem is that the WURFL data is not being loaded to begin with.  I would first delete the contents of your cache/ and persistence/ folders, then make sure your config includes something like $config->allowReload(true); and visit your site.  It should take a minute or so to generate the persistence data, and after that all should be well.